How is the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem being applied to $\ell^\infty$ in this proof?
I have been reading this proof of Gromov's Theorem from Terry Tao's blog: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/a-proof-of-gromovs-theorem/
At the end of Section 2, Tao applies the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem to a sequence of functions in $\ell^\infty(G)$, where $G$ is a finitely-generated group. However, the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem does not apply to $\ell^\infty(G)$ with its norm topology unless $G$ is finite. Can anyone tell me which version of the theorem is being applied here?
One idea I had is that perhaps Tao is using the topology of point-wise convergence rather than the norm-topology, but I haven't been able to find a version of Arzela-Ascoli that applies to that setting.
Another thing to note is that, in the context of Tao's proof, we don't expect the limit to lie in $\ell^\infty(G)$ (because this would give a non-trivial bounded harmonic function on an arbitrary amenable group, but these don't exist on, for instance, abelian groups). Perhaps we are taking a limit in the space of all complex-valued functions of the group with the topology of point-wise convergence?

The space $\ell^\infty(G)$ can be identified  with $C(\beta G),$ the space of continuous functions on the Stone-Cech  compactification of $G.$

@RyszardSzwarc That's true! However this would give a limit still in $\ell^\infty$ and, as I explained in the post, we do not expect the limit to belong to $\ell^\infty$. I also cannot see why the sequence of functions in the proof should be equicontinuous when considered as functions on $\beta G$.
I am beginning to suspect that Tao misspoke, and actually meant Tychonov's Theorem, which would allow you to take a point-wise subsequence limit here, and the limit would not necessarily belong to $\ell^\infty$.

The Ascoli-Arzela theorem is not being applied in $\ell^\infty(G)$.
Instead, it is being applied in (spaces of functions on) balls around the origin of $G$ in the word metric, those balls being finite sets. There is a hidden diagonalization argument taking place here: having normalized the sequence $H_n * G_n$ to be zero at the identity, one applies Ascoli-Arzela on the ball of radius $1$ (to get a subsequence converging on that ball), then one applies Ascoli-Arzela on the ball of radius $2$, then on the ball of radius $3$, etc., then one takes a diagonal sequence to get a sequence converging everywhere.
Perhaps one could say that the point of this argument is to promote "asymptotic harmonicity" of the sequence $H_n * G_n$ to harmonicity of the limit of the diagonal sequence.
Of course, as you note, one could simply use the words "Tychonoff Theorem" instead of the words "Ascoli-Arzela Theorem"; on (the space of functions on) a finite metric space, such as a finite group or a ball in a finitely generated group, they boil down to the same thing.
